# Saving a screenshot file via options menu item android

Tags: java, android

I have been handed an existing android project and it's been years since I've done any development with android.

I have to take a screenshot and save it so that a user can send it in an email or text message.

I have the screenshot and believe I know how to save it, but I think I'm missing a step. I'm testing on a device not avd.

[EDIT]
When testing I have the device connected via USB, I run the app via Eclipse, I take my screenshot, then exit the app, and open the gallery, I cannot see the image file, leaving the gallery open, if I unplug the usb, the image appears in the gallery.

The screenshot and save is taken via an options menu item. Most of it is processed behind the scenes and once done displays a toast saying that it has been saved.

As you can see below I have just called takeScreenshot() from the MenuItem, however it's like it doesn't finish saving the file until the activity has finished.

What could I be missing? Do I need to create another class for this procedure?

```
public class GraphView extends Activity {

    ....

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.take_screenshot_menu_item)
        {
            takeScreenshot();
            return true;
        }
    }

    private void takeScreenshot() {
        Date now = new Date();
        android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_hh:mm:ss", now);

        try {
            // image naming and path  to include sd card  appending name you choose for file
            String imgPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Pictures/SMA/";
            String filename = now + ".jpg";

            // create bitmap screen capture
            View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
            v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
            v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

            File imagePath = new File(imgPath);
            imagePath.mkdirs();

            File outputFile = new File(imagePath, filename);
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
            int quality = 100;
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, outputStream);
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();

            showMsg("Screenshot saved to...");
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            // Several error may come out with file handling or OOM
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void showMsg(String msg) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(GraphView.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, toast.getXOffset() / 2, toast.getYOffset() / 2);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: try using switch case with onOptionsItemSelected

Comment: i guess you are missing return statement as below return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly sure how this helped but it did. Since the image file wasn't showing up immediately in the gallery after saving, I added the following:

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(
        Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
        Uri.parse("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())
        ));
```

This must have refreshed the gallery in some form or fashion and I can now see the image file straight away

Answer (score 0):

change your onOptionsItemSelected() as below

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.take_screenshot_menu_item:
        takeScreenshot();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Hi Karan, I'm afraid this didn't change anything, my exact steps are in an edit in the question